# Sort element lines by a sum VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Can i short a textbox by a sum lines? example: I have textbox:

```
Textbox1.Lines(0)= 1 10
Textbox1.Lines(1)= 1 11
Textbox1.Lines(2)= 2 10
Textbox1.Lines(3)= 3 11
Textbox1.Lines(4)= 2 12
```

Expected Output: preferably if possible, write the sum that is. with :( sum = x) preferably short by descending, probably an example of sorting code would help me, but I can do that too, but for now I don't know how to order according to the sum of the lines. just to sort them out, this would be a model, but to know the sum of each one as well.

```
{ LstScan = 2 12, DrwSum = 14 }
{ LstScan = 3 11, DrwSum = 14 }
{ LstScan = 2 10, DrwSum = 12 }
{ LstScan = 1 11, DrwSum = 12 }
{ LstScan = 1 10, DrwSum = 11 }
```

Comment: First things first, that first code snippet is bad. Don't use the `Lines` property over and over like that. The reason is that it doesn't refer to any "live" data. Each time you use the property, the control has to create a new array. What you should be doing is getting the property value once and assigning that array to a variable, using that variable to modify the array, then assigning the array back to the property.

Comment: With that in mind, your question now has nothing at all to do with the lines of a `TextBox`. You're simply sorting a `String` array. You can do that any way you want. Ignoring LINQ, the obvious way is using the `Array.Sort` overload that sorts an array based on the "key" values in another. You can create a second array, populate it with your sums and then call `Array.Sort`. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c# this would look like:

```
var list = new[] { "2 12", "3 11", "2 10", "1 11", "1 10" }
    .Select(o => Tuple.Create<string, int>(o, o.Split(' ').Sum(x => int.Parse(x))));
var result = list.OrderByDescending(o => o.Item2).ToList();
```

In vb.net it would be:

```
Dim list = {"2 12", "3 11", "2 10", "1 11", "1 10"}
    .[Select](Function(o) Tuple.Create(Of String, Integer)(o, o.Split(" "c).Sum(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x))))
Dim result = list.OrderByDescending(Function(o) o.Item2).ToList()
```

Comment: This uses Linq so you need to add reference to it as well.

Comment: `Dim lst As List(Of String) = TextBox1.Lines.ToList`